# Is there a way to find out whether the user microsoft account is personal account or enterprise account?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office-js, onedrive

I am working on outlook web add-in which is using onedrive filepicker v8 SDK. In order to use onedrive filepicker v8, i need to provide configurations explicitly for both sharepoint and onedrive. This web add-in will be accessible to normal consumers as well as enterprise users. I want to know if there is way to find out, via graph API or Office.js API, whether the user is using personal Microsoft account or enterprise account.

One way is to decode the token. But i have seen that for sharepoint enterpise users, issues token is JWT which can be decoded and this is'nt the case with personal accounts where the issued token is not JWT and cannot be decoded.

Can someone help me regarding this ??

Comment: Check this: [Account types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.userprofile?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-userprofile-accounttype-member)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a direct Office.js API or Microsoft Graph API method to determine whether a user is using a personal Microsoft account or an enterprise account solely based on the token or without decoding it.